# MutationObservers - Some nodes added are not detected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mutation-observers

I have a content script which listens for the insertion of text-nodes on some websites. It's working great, except on Facebook. Some of the text-nodes inserted are not detected by the script.

#### script.js

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type  === "characterData") {
            console.log(mutation.target);
        } else {
            for (var x = 0; x < mutation.addedNodes.length; x++) {
                var node = mutation.addedNodes[x];
                if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    console.log(node);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true });
```

If I allow logging of all node types, I can see the parent nodes of these text nodes in my log.

Thanks.

Comment: In console on Facebook page script works(Chrome 34). How do you run this script? P.S. I think the question is not relevant for today (May 14).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48630241/16458492). If a script "builds" elements outside of the DOM and then attaches the root, only the root will be reported as an added node. [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) can be used to traverse the added node's subtree to find the text.

```
for (const addedNode of mutation.addedNodes) {
    if (addedNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        console.log(addedNode);
    } else {
        // If added node is not a Text node, traverse subtree to find Text nodes
        const nodes = document.createTreeWalker(addedNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
        while (nodes.nextNode()) {
            console.log(nodes.currentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a way of detecting even when the debugger is opened on the website. I am guessing they have a way to detect mutation observers as well. They might just be blocking your content scripts. Besides I wouldn't really use the whole document as my object. Just try to monitor what you want using document.querySelector.